# Windows mouse pointer takes a bit to reappear after suspend

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, suspend

I've noticed a strange behaviour on my Windows 10, when resuming from the suspend, the mouse pointer takes some seconds (like 5-10) to reappear on screen, so i can't actually use my mouse during that time period. Do you know what could be the issue?

Windows update version: 21H1 
Build version: 19043.985

Comment: Do you have a mechanical HDD or a SSD?

Comment: @Ramhound i have an SSD

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Windows+R and type `control powercfg.cpl,,3` and press enter.
2. Scroll down to `USB Settings` then `USB selective suspend setting`.
3. Disable it, then press OK.

Also...

1. Press Windows+R and type `devmgmt.msc` and press enter.
2. Open `Human Interface Devices` and double-click your mouse.
3. Go to the `Power Management` tab and uncheck `Allow the computer to turn of this device...` and press OK.

Restart the computer, and that should take care of it. If not, comment and I will add some more things to try.

Comment: I'm using the touchpad, not a mouse. Should i try doing it anyway?

Comment: Yes, because internally Windows doesn't really know if it's a touchpad or a mouse, it's just a mouse input device